# General formula of a composite quadratic function

Tags: functions

I've already found a general formula to composite linear functions, i.e., if I have a function $f(x)=ax+b$, I can find a formula to $f^{(n)}(x)$ as function of the constants $a,b$ and $n$.

I want to know if it's possible to find a formula to the n-composite function of $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but computations get very cumbersome. I recommend starting with derivatives and then integrate the results.

for example let $$f(x)=g(g(x))$$

Then $$f'(x)=g'(g(x))g'(x)= (2ag(x) +b)(2ax+b) = 4a^2xg(x)+2ab (x+g(x))+b^2$$

Simplify and integrate and find the constant of integration by $x=0$.

Comment: I didn't understand, when I said $f^{(n)}(x)$ I meant the n-composite instead of n-derivative. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I know. I told you that it is easier if you  first take derivative of the nth composite and integrate the result. The derivative of  the iterations is just the product of derivatives which in this case is very simple. Look at the example please.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for a very good question.